# Why should i use redux react native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

As per other developers suggest redux is required for more complex projects please anyone guide me for it

Comment: You should google it. For real, you will find a lot of information on google about this. What I can say is that Redux is awesome to manage your state and avoid passing props down to child components. But once again, please google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux improves the scalability of your app a lot. As more stuff is added to your app, the complexity of code doesn't increase by a lot if you have redux as your state manager. Also, it's a great way to get state persistence in your App.

Edit: Redux Thunk vs Saga-

Now that's totally up to personal choice, it's a community dividing question, 50% would tell you to use Thunk then others would tell you to go with Saga.

> Redux-thunk and Redux-saga are both middleware libraries for Redux.
>   In terms of implementation, Redux-Thunk and Redux-Saga couldn't possibly be more different. However, in terms of what you can do with them… well, they're actually very very similar. But not the same. Redux-Thunk and Redux-Saga differ in a few important ways.
>   You might think the biggest difference is in the syntax. Although it's true that writing and reasoning about thunks and sagas are quite different, there's something bigger.
>   Thunks can never act in response to an action. Redux-Saga, on the other hand, subscribes to the store and can trigger a saga to run or continue when a certain action is dispatched.

I personally prefer Redux-Thunk because I found it's syntax to my taste.
I hope that answers your question.

Comment: which one is better middleware Saga or Thunk 
thank you !

Comment: @pradipkoravi I updated my answer. I hope it helps you and if you're satisfied with it then green tick it so that it can help others :)